# Use System.Diagnostics in windows store application

Tags: c#, namespaces, windows-store-apps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the equivalent of the System.Diagnostic.Process on WinRT (C#)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765699/whats-the-equivalent-of-the-system-diagnostic-process-on-winrt-c)

I use `System.Diagnostics` namespace for working with process functions in windows forms application.

Now I want to know is there any possible way so that I can use this function in windows store application?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you're trying to achieve? Sample code of what you're doing in the Windows forms application would help.

Comment: @DamirArh I can't use System.Diagnostics.Process class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that they are not going to work. Looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441592.aspx), it contains all the entities in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace that are available to Windows Store applications. If the method/class is not listed in this, then you can't use it. I would expect the code to not even be present in the framework that is used by these apps to prevent using them via introspection.

It's most likely that even if you could invoke the methods, you would find that they would fail due to security blocks that have been put in place to prevent Windows Store apps from interacting with the desktop.