# How to use Diagnostic in WinRT App

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml

I need to launch or run an windows exe file from a OEM in Win store App.

can below be used? I try but have error but why since diagnostic is in the framework

```
   using System.Diagnostics;

   Process myProcess = new Process();

   try
    {
      myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

      // here I point to the OEM windows exe file

      myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\HelloWorld.exe";

      myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

      myProcess.Start();


     }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
     }
```

-- Update

@ Michal :
Thank you. This method works using URI. 
One problem :

the WinRT app goes into background after launching. How to make the winRT app not going background?

Is there any other way? I need to integrate the Exe from the OEM into Win Store App.

Note:

I want to know is this can be done or I am doing something which is not allowed?

If I didnot make my case clearer, please tell me what I miss.

I tried it but it did not work. So my solution should be using similar approach like Diagnostic but what it can be?

Comment: Did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110070/use-system-diagnostics-in-windows-store-application

Comment: This question can be also useful:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330858/launch-another-windows-store-app

Comment: You cannot execute another .exe application from WinRT app. That goes against principle of their sandboxing, distribution and architecture. If you need to communicate with other application check "contracts": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/windows/apps/hh464906.aspx

Comment: @ Ladislav, Understand completely what you say. we dont plan to list the app in App Store, we do it for business with side load. we need some help how to wrap the win32 api in to win store file so we can use it in win store app.

Answer (score 0):

Recycling bits from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0a822355-909f-44b4-9c79-cb986087fe27/after-launching-or-activate-an-app-the-main-app-goes-into-background?forum=winappswithcsharp

This is expected behavior and there's no good way around it. Launching a file or protocol switches to the default handler with no expectation of return.

Launching an app via protocol like this a hack in the first place. Since you are a side-loaded app look into writing a Brokered Windows Runtime Component to allow proper use of desktop API and communication with a desktop back-end.

See the Brokered Windows Runtime Component docs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn630195.aspx