# System.Diagnostics.Process not working in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm working in a UWP app in which I need to launch Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer when the users clicks on a button.

I've found that the way to do it is calling the `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` but I get:

> The type or namespace name 'Process' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Diagnostics'

I've tried to install it with NuGet but I've gotten several Exceptions also...

I've also tried using Launcher, but it hasn't done anything:

`await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("LINK"));`

Does anyone know how to implement what I need?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the equivalent of the System.Diagnostic.Process on WinRT (C#)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12765699/993547).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open external application from Universal Windows app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330805/open-external-application-from-universal-windows-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use [LaunchUriAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore,Version%3Dv5.0);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)
To ask Windows to launch the app associated with a protocol (ex: http://) and pass the Uri to it.

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://danvy.tv"));
```

In this case, your default browser will open http://danvy.tv .

Comment: Got it, but the browser is not opened... it does nothing

Comment: What happen is you run "http://danvy.tv" (Windows+R) ? It should launch your default browser

Comment: Did you solve your problem? Update your question accordingly please.

Comment: It doesn't work at all. It's not even recognised, if I call the library I get a compiler error. I don't know what to do

Comment: If Windows can't execute (launch your default browser) when your execute "http://danvy.tv" you have a problem with your system, not your app. Talking about the project, you don't have to add any library. Could you please create a project using the Universal blank app template. Add a button to the page and execute the LaunchUriAsync in it.

Comment: now works perfectly... i don't understand why, but many thanks! :)

Comment: Good luck for the rest of your app :)

Comment: Thanks for everything @danvy :)