# Can't get Process.Start to work in C#

Tags: c#

I've been trying to run a command from an app written in C#, and all I've read had to do with using System.Diagnostics.Process.Start to run it. However, whenever I try to use this function, the compiler throws an error telling me that 'The type or namespace name 'Process' does not exist in the namespace System.Diagnostics'.

When I try to write the command, intellisense doesn't show anything about "Process" inside the System.Diagnostics namespace.

This doesn't work:

```
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace App2
{
    sealed partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {

        }
        protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", "help"); // This is giving me an error

        }

    }
}
```

EDIT: I just tried creating a new Windows Forms project, and I could find System.Diagnostics.Process.Start. Does anyone know how can I run a command from an Universal Windows App, since it's apparently not supported?

Comment: Could it be that you are targeting PCL or some platform that does not support it (iOS)?

Comment: That exact line of code works for me.  Please provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Just added an example, hope that explains my issue. I recently installed Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10, could that be the issue? It just seems as if there was no "Process" in System.Diagnostics. Also I'm building the app in x64 architecture.

Comment: You might find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12765699/whats-the-equivalent-of-the-system-diagnostic-process-on-winrt-c useful

Comment: Is it specifically the help section in cmd you are trying to start or something else? Maybe there's another solution if you give us the full picture?

Comment: Not sure about your target. But it seems that it could be treated as starting an external application from an UWA. If so, you may look into this question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32330805/open-external-application-from-universal-windows-app).

Comment: Don't change your question halfway through. The answer to this question is "starting a process isn't supported in universal apps" because the process you want to start probably isn't on the phone or the xbox. Post a new question if you have a follow-up question.  (Of course since your follow-up question is "how do I do something impossible?" I would not expect answers other than "don't try to do that.")

Comment: Thanks Colin, I think I'm going to create a background app with an url scheme so it can run the command. If you want to write a more detailed answer for the sake of the question I'll happily mark it as best

Comment: Hi Patrick, what I want to do exactly is run a phyton script to turn ON a light at my house.